# forEach loop, stacks classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, foreach

I have a hmtl template which replicates with a forEach loop. And I use .length of the template to give the new divs class names that are unique.

The problem is that it the newest template has all the previous classes.

```
"residentRetainRequest check jqbr_active residentRetainRequest-0 residentRetainRequest-1 residentRetainRequest-2 residentRetainRequest-3"
```

How do I get rid of the previous classes and only keep the latest? So the result above is "residentRetainRequest check jqbr_active residentRetainRequest-3" instead.

[Parts of the code](https://jsfiddle.net/q5h1nb3g/)

The reason behind:

```
temp.find('.residentRetainRequest').attr 'data-key', 'residentRetainRequest-' + iCnt
```

Is that i use another function, and use this to call it.

Comment: You identify the element for which you want to add the `class` right? once the class is added remove that `classname` by chaning events like `temp.find('.someclass').addClass('newClass').removeClass('someClass');`

Comment: or  just add the class with the current count to the latest element only: `temp.find('.residentRetainRequest').last().addClass("residentRetainRequest-" + iCnt)`

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. But I want all the elements to have
`residentRetainRequest- + iCnt` as class name. but only one. Not `"residentRetainRequest check jqbr_active residentRetainRequest-0 residentRetainRequest-1 residentRetainRequest-2 residentRetainRequest-3"`

Comment: So just select the last element (instead of always all elements with .residentRetainRequest) and add the class residentRetainRequest-i.

Comment: Thanks, It solved it! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be this line of code which is always selecting all items with class residentRetainRequest:

```
temp.find('.residentRetainRequest').addClass("residentRetainRequest-" + iCnt);
```

Instead this code will select only the last item to add residentRetainRequest with current count i:

```
temp.find('.residentRetainRequest').last().addClass("residentRetainRequest-" + iCnt)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was using .removeClass as mention.

```
temp.find('.residentRetainRequest').addClass("residentRetainRequest-" + iCnt)
temp.find('.residentRetainRequest').removeClass('residentRetainRequest-' + (iCnt - 1))
```

Therefore i will get rid of the previous classes and only have the last one remaning.

Comment: In my opinion two lines of code are not necessary for this as they add and remove again. Also what about for example if you have indexes 1,2,3,4. You add 5 and remove 4 but you still keep 1,2,3. But anyway, it depends on what you want to achieve. if it is working all is fine.